# MySQL: get the record position number from a query

Tags: mysql

I want to know the ordinal (?) position of a record that is returned in a query.

The general answer on the Internet is this:

```
SET @row=0;
SELECT (@row:=@row+1) AS row, ename, empno FROM emp ORDER BY empno;
+-----+--------+-------+
| row | ename  | empno |
+-----+--------+-------+
|   1 | SMITH  |  7369 |
|   2 | ALLEN  |  7499 |
|   3 | WARD   |  7521 |
|   4 | JONES  |  7566 |
|   5 | MARTIN |  7654 |
|   6 | BLAKE  |  7698 |
|   7 | CLARK  |  7782 |
|   8 | SCOTT  |  7788 |
|   9 | KING   |  7839 |
|  10 | TURNER |  7844 |
|  11 | ADAMS  |  7876 |
|  12 | JAMES  |  7900 |
|  13 | FORD   |  7902 |
|  14 | MILLER |  7934 |
+-----+--------+-------+
```

But it doesn't work at all for me. The list is ordered correctly using the ORDER BY, but the row column is in a random order, instead of being sequential.

Hoping that someone will know the answer to this, rather than advising me why I shouldn't be doing it (there are lots of technical reasons why, too many to go into!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved myself :|

Create a subquery listing all the records, then a query selecting all those records, along with the (row=row+1) bit, then another query which selects all those records, and uses a WHERE clause to find your record.

So you have 3 nested queries. Lowest one selects all, middle one adds the row info, top one adds the WHERE clause.